# Socket-io redis network degradation after update

Tags: node.js, networking, redis, publish-subscribe

For a long time we have used socket.io 1.7.2 with redis pub/sub. It sended messages between several servers and all were ok. Redis incoming and outcoming traffic was about 20-30 Mb\s
But some time ago we desided to update 1.7.2 to 3.1.2(both server and client)
And faced with problem: Incoming traffic for redis was the same(no logic changed)
but outcoming traffic increased x10 from 30 to 900Mb\s. After some optimisations(removed some emits) we reduced outcoming traffic to 300Mb - But it is still large number.

First I thought that it was because of dasabled perMessageDeflate in 3 version.
I have enabled it but no luck.

My code starts like:

```
server      = https.createServer({}, express());
io = require('socket.io')();    
io.attach(server, {
    cors: {
       origin: "*"
    },
    maxHttpBufferSize: 1e8,//100mb
    perMessageDeflate: true
});
    
var redisio = require('socket.io-redis');
...
io.adapter(redisio({ 
    pubClient: pub, 
    subClient: sub 
}));
```

We can make other optimisations, but I want to understand why such problem appeared and what to do with that?

Comment: the reason is that socket.io compress messages from client to server, but because it is optional value for clients - in the middle messages are not compressed. And between servers(via redis) it goes in uncompressed way. So the only way to make messages compressed - is to compress it manually before sending.